# How to dynamically declare an annotation [DataFormat(DataFormatString)] to represent a value with units?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6, data-annotations

How can I use the annotation `[DataFormat(DataFormatString="")]` on a numeric value along with a `Units` value (which will vary from entry to entry) to display a value with a label (such as `"$1.00 per Pound"`?

In an ASP.NET MVC 5 application, I have three entities: `Product`, `Store`, and `Price` (Price is a bridge entity).  `Product` has the fields `int Amount` and `enum Units` which stores for example 10 Ounce, or 1 Gallon.  In `Price` I am trying to figure out how to create a nicely formatted `UnitPrice` field, which is a calculated field that divides the Product price by the amount of a given unit, and displays it with the correct units.  An example is a 10 ounce can of soup that costs $1.00 would read `$0.10 per Ounce.` when displayed in the view.

In `Price` I am able to use the following code snippet to properly calculate the value and format it with a trailing string literal `" per unit"` when displayed in the view:

```
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString="{0:$#,##0.00' per unit'}")]
    [Display(Name = "Unit Price")]
    public decimal UnitPrice
    {
        get { return Value / Product.Amount; }
    }
```

However, when I tried something like:

```
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString="{0:$#,##0.00' per " + this.Product.Amount + "'}")]
```

In place of the 1st annotation, Visual Studio tells me that keyword "this" is not in the current context.  If I remove this, then it thinks Product is referencing the class instead of the field.  if I change the name of the field to anything else, it tells me "an object reference is required for the non-static field, method or property."

I am at loss for an elegant solution to this.  I know I could make a separate field to handle it, like this:

```
// Edited to include String.Format
[Display(Name = "Unit Price")]
public String LabeledUnitPrice
{
    get { return String.Format("{0:$#,##0.00}", UnitPrice) + " per " + this.Product.Units; }
}
```

I could also handle this in the view, but I would prefer for it to be handled all together here in the model code, to keep things the simplest.  Is it possible, or is there another way to do so?

My relevant code:

```
public enum UnitType
{
    Each, Pound, Ounce, Fluid_Ounce, Liter, Gallon
}

public class Product

{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 1)]
    public String Name { get; set; }

    [RegularExpression(@"^[0-9]{0,12}$")]
    public String UPC { get; set; }

    public int CategoryID { get; set; }

    public int Amount { get; set; }
    public UnitType Units{ get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Amount")]
    public string AmountInUnits
    {
        get { return Amount + " " + Units; }
    }


    public virtual ICollection<Price> Prices { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
}

public class Price
{
        public int PriceID { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
        [Display(Name="Price")]
        public decimal Value { get; set; }
        public int ProductID { get; set; }
        public int StoreID { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM-dd-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        [Display(Name = "Entry Date")]
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }

        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString="{0:$#,##0.00' per unit'}")]
        [Display(Name = "Unit Price")]
        public decimal UnitPrice
        {
            get { return Value / Product.Amount; }
        }

        public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
        public virtual Store Store { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Dataannotations are evaluated at compile time and cant contain any runtime data. What's wrong with your calculated property `LabeledUnitPrice`? These are perfectly fine and make sense.

Comment: Technically, there's nothing wrong with `LabeledUnitPrice`, as it functions perfectly.  I just wanted a better solution if possible.  And by better, I mean to avoid an unnecessary instance variable by fixing some small detail I'm missing, I feel like that is a better solution to the problem.

Comment: Note that I still need the calculated field `UnitPrice` as the application needs that value to compare Prices of Products elsewhere.

Comment: A calculated property won't be an instance variable. I think you're going to be hard pressed to find a solution better than ~2 lines of code. These are very common.

Answer (score 1):

Attributes with behavior are generally a [bad design practice](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/13/passive-attributes/). While making attributes display static formats is acceptable in most cases, as you have discovered it is difficult to customize if you need the data to be dynamic.

Your best bet is to make a ViewModel that contains the calculations and display logic so they are neither part of your model or your view.